# How did Manoach not know he was speaking with an Angel?

Tags: malach-angel, navi-prophets, shoftim--book-of

In the passage in Shoftim chapter 13, Manoach and his wife speak with an Angel. His wife in verse 6 tells him she has spoken with an Angel. A few verses later, the verse says that Manoach didn’t know he was speaking with an Angel. How did he not know at that point after his wife told him?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Re-read the verse. Manoach's wife told him she met a prophet (איש האלוקים/man of God is a title for a prophet) who **looked like** an angel:

> "The woman went and told her husband, “A man of God came to me; **he looked like an angel** of God, very frightening. I did not ask him where he was from, nor did he tell me his name."

For this reason Manoach then prays to Hashem to send again the "prophet".

Comment: Great point! Thank you.

Comment: @user you're welcome.